# How do i show the proper count value in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-analysis

```
CH Gayle          17
YK Pathan         16
AB de Villiers    15
DA Warner         14
SK Raina          13
RG Sharma         13
MEK Hussey        12
AM Rahane         12
MS Dhoni          12
G Gambhir         12
```

I have a series like this. I want to plot the player on the x axis and their respective value on the y axis. I tried this code:

```
man_of_match=(matches['player_of_match'].value_counts())
sns.countplot(x=(man_of_match),data=matches,color='B')
sns.plt.show()
```

But with this code, it plots the frequency of the numeric value, i.e on x axis 12 gets plotted and the count on y axis becomes 4. Similarly for 13 on x axis it shows 2 on y axis.

How do i make the x axis show the name of the player and the y axis the corresponding value of the player.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sns.countplot` is meant to do the counting for you.  You are counting yourself with `value_counts` then plotting the counts of counts.  Pass `matches` directly to `sns.countplot`

```
ax = sns.countplot(matches['player_of_match'], color='B')
plt.sca(ax)
plt.xticks(rotation=90);
```

[image]

---

If you want to limit it to the top 10 players.  Use `value_counts` as you did.  But use matplotlib directly, to plot.

```
ax = matches['player_of_match'].value_counts().head(10).plot.bar(width=.8, color='R')
ax.set_xlabel('player_of_match')
ax.set_ylabel('count')
```

[image]

You can get it to look a lot like the seaborn plot

```
kws = dict(width=.8, color=sns.color_palette('pastel'))
ax = matches['player_of_match'].value_counts().head(10).plot.bar(**kws)
ax.set_xlabel('player_of_match')
ax.set_ylabel('count')
ax.grid(False, axis='x')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @user517696 if this solved your issue, please click the green arrow to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: This method is plotting all the players.  I just need the top 10 players and not the whole list.